# Display the content on the same page based on the user selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to apply routing inside an Angular controller. I have multiple tabs, when the user clicks on tab2, it displays a list of
options the user can select. When the user selects the link "Red" , it should display the content of red.html on the right side of the same content area in tab2, based on the user selection it should show content on the right-hand side.

Demo here : https://plnkr.co/edit/lYOaA91ddqASHR3PwULz?p=preview

In the above code demo, when the user selects Tab2, some links are shown in tab2 which when user click on the link it is routed to other html page whose content should be displayed on the right-hand side of the same tab.

Below is the js code for routing when the user selects any link on Tab2. Any suggestions how to perform routing inside a controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.html"
    }).when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    });
});
```

Any inputs on how to perform routing from inside a ng-controller.

Comment: I can suggest you to use **ui-router** for nested routes: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I'm already using ng-route. Question is how to route when using the lniks inside the ng-controller.@CommercialSuicide

Answer (score 0):

Use the below HTML:

```
<li><a href="/">Main</a> </li>
<li><a href="/#!/red">Red</a></li>
<li><a href="/#!/green">Green</a></li>
```

Comment: where is the plnkr link?

Comment: put my HTML into your plnkr.

Comment: I had..but its not working ,can you edit and update my plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/lYOaA91ddqASHR3PwULz?p=preview

Comment: i updated the code on your plnkr, please also check HTML(green.html, red.html...) file path which you mentioned is there!!!!!

Comment: Do u really want to provide an answer? If you see my plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/lYOaA91ddqASHR3PwULz?p=preview all required html's(green.html,red.html) are there. But your code is not working. If want to provide the full help try to else please give space so that someone else would help...@Syed Amir Hussain

Comment: I have fixed the problem, check your plnkr now, it is fixed...its working

Comment: @Syes Amir Hussain - Is this the correct plkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/lYOaA91ddqASHR3PwULz?p=preview . Because it is not yet working. I think best thing would be you update the plnkr link and post it here. thanks,,